# Injecting interface implementation into script

Tags: delphi, interface, dwscript

How one is supposed to "inject interface implementation" into script? Say I define an interface type in TdwsUnit, like

```
IFoo = interface
  procedure Bar;
end;
```

now how can I implement an function which returns `array of IFoo` (or List of IFoo or even single IFoo for that matter) in the script?

I tryed to add an IFoo item to the `Instances` collection of the unit but that resulted in error:

> Syntax Error: TdwsUnit: "uTest" -- TdwsInstance: "tmp" -- AutoInstantiate is true but DataType "IFoo" is not a class

Creating an variable of IFoo type compiles, and it's `OnReadVar` event fires, but what I'm supposed to return there as `value`?

I guess I could define a class for each interface and then create instances of those classes but it seems kinda roundabout way as I don't need the classes per se, I just want to expose information to the script via interface types... so is there a way to return an array of "interface instances" to the script?

**UPDATE**

So, I have figured out how to return an array from Delphi side to script side, now I need to find a way to create the "interface instances" to put into the result array... What I have so far:

In the descendant of `TdwsUnit` I create an function (actually a method but I guess thats irrelevant)

```
meth := typClass.Methods.Add;
meth.Name := 'GetData';
meth.ResultType := 'array of String';
meth.OnEval := H_EvalFnc_GetData;
```

and then in the `OnEval`

```
procedure TMyUnit.H_EvalFnc_GetData(Info: TProgramInfo; ExtObject: TObject);
begin
  Info.ResultVars.Member['Length'].Value := 2;
  Info.ResultVars.Element([0]).Value := 'Hello';
  Info.ResultVars.Element([1]).Value := 'Word';
end;
```

Now I need to change the result type to `array of IFoo` and figure out how to create array elements in the `OnEval` hadler... any hints on how to that are welcome.

Comment: Do you use the latest unstable version of DWS? AFAIR interfaces marshalling has just being added. And please show the code in which you bind your interface.

Comment: @ArnaudBouchez Yes, I got the latest version from svn after your comment in newsgroup. I don't have any code to show, I'm total DSW newbie and not quite sure how this thing works... As I wrote in my question I tried to add an item to the instances collection but got error. So I quess my question is what's the correct way to "bind an interface"?

Comment: The exposing is the there, but the marshalling isn't there yet. So currently you have to marshall manually through events on the Delphi side.

Comment: @EricGrange Could you please post an example/explanation how to do it? I browsed throught demo projects but didn't found anything using interface types in that manner...